# Calculating Count for IEnumerable (Non Generic)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

Can anyone help me with a `Count` extension method for `IEnumerable` (non generic interface).

I know it is not supported in LINQ but how to write it manually?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The simplest form would be:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable source)
{
    int c = 0;
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

You can then improve on this by querying for `ICollection`:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable source)
{
    var col = source as ICollection;
    if (col != null)
        return col.Count;

    int c = 0;
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

**Update**

As Gerard points out in the comments, non-generic `IEnumerable` does not inherit `IDisposable` so the normal `using` statement won't work. It is probably still important to attempt to dispose of such enumerators if possible - an iterator method implements `IEnumerable` and so may be passed indirectly to this `Count` method. Internally, that iterator method will be depending on a call to `Dispose` to trigger its own `try`/`finally` and `using` statements.

To make this easy in other circumstances too, you can make your own version of the `using` statement that is less fussy at compile time:

```
public static void DynamicUsing(object resource, Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable d = resource as IDisposable;
        if (d != null)
            d.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the updated `Count` method would then be:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable source) 
{
    var col = source as ICollection; 
    if (col != null)
        return col.Count; 

    int c = 0;
    var e = source.GetEnumerator();
    DynamicUsing(e, () =>
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
            c++;
    });

    return c;
}
```

Comment: "querying for IList" - or querying for it's base interface ICollection

Comment: I tried out this extension, the `using` gives a compile error for `System.Collections.IEnumerable`. I changed the code to `Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` which compiles.

Answer (score 60):

```
yourEnumerable.Cast<object>().Count()
```

*To the comment about performance:*

I think this is a good example of premature optimization but here you go:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static int Count(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        int res = 0;

        foreach (var item in source)
            res++;

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel's answer that checks for `ICollection` is better, for what it is worth...

Comment: @Marc The first `.Cast<object>().Count()` already makes that check (generic and non-generic). But yes, the second solution could be improved by checks.

Comment: What's the point of casting it into the generic IEnumerable<T> version ? This would defeat the reason behind using the non generic IEnumerable - exactly for when you do not know / do not care about the elements type. You will not, then, be able to do any compile-time casting to the elements type because they are not known (if they are known - the IEnumerable being used should be generic in the first place).

Comment: If **all** what is needed in the end is a way of getting the total number of elements, perhaps the object type should not be IEnumerable but ICollection. Both the generic and non generic versions provide a Count property.

Comment: I agree with "premature optimisation" argument in the edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

Different types of IEnumerable have different optimal methods for determining count; unfortunately, there's no general-purpose means of knowing which method will be best for any given IEnumerable, nor is there even any standard means by which an IEmumerable can indicate which of the following techniques is best:

1. Simply ask the object directly.  Some types of objects that support IEnumerable, such as Array, List and Collection, have properties which can directly report the number of elements in them.

   Enumerate all items, discarding them, and count the number of items enumerated.

   Enumerate all items into a list, and then use the list if it's necessary to use the enumeration again.

Each of the above will be optimal in different cases.

Answer (score 4):

I think the type chosen to represent your sequence of elements should have been **ICollection instead of IEnumerable**, in the first place.

Both `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` provide a Count property - plus - every ICollection implements IEnumearable as well.