# How to get the items count from an IList<> got as an object?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting, ilist

In a method, I get an `object`.

In some situation, this `object` can be an `IList` of "something" (I have no control over this "something").

I am trying to:

1. Identify that this object is an `IList` (of something)
2. Cast the `object` into an "`IList<something>`" to be able to get the `Count` from it.

For now, I am stuck and looking for ideas.

Comment: Is the `Count` *all* you want? If so, you don't need it to be an `IList<T>`, a simple `IEnumerable` will do.

Comment: Yes, `Count` is all that I want. However, I can't see any `Count` in `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check if your `object` implements `IList` using `is`.

Then you can cast your `object` to `IList` to get the count.

```
object myObject = new List<string>();

// check if myObject implements IList
if (myObject  is IList)
{
   int listCount = ((IList)myObject).Count;
}
```

Comment: Ah, great, this is what I missed. I was looking for `IList<T>` being an `IList`. But as `List<T>` and `Collection<T>` are `IList`s, This is enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (obj is ICollection)
{
    var count = ((ICollection)obj).Count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a benefit of casting into `ICollection` over casting into `IList`?

Comment: Will work with more types of collections, casting to IEnumerable and reading .Count() instead of .Count will work with even more.

Comment: @DannyVarod but `IEnumerable.Count()` risks enumerating the collection in order to count its items.

Comment: Depends on actual type of collection. For lists it won't.

Comment: @phoog, This is exactly what I was suspicious about, but as it won't be the case for lists according to DannyVarod' statemtent, it seems to be a good compromise to be able to handle ost of the situations. Developers "just" need to be aware of it.

Comment: @remio Actually, I was just looking at ILSpy, and the `IEnumerable` approach won't work for your use case.  The `Count()` extension method is for `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`, so you're still left with the problem of determining the type of the collection's members before you can call `Count()`.

Comment: @remio Additionally, if you call `Cast<object>` as suggested by AakashM, you're no longer counting the members of the list directly; you're getting them from the cast iterator, which doesn't give access to the `Count` property of the wrapped object.

Comment: You can determine generic type parameter then use that for a more specific cast, however, that would be an overkill for this simple situation. That is why I suggested ICollection at first.

Answer (score 1):

```
        object o = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        //...

        if (o is IList)
        {
            IList l = o as IList;
            Console.WriteLine(l.Count);
        }
```

This prints 3, because int[] is a IList.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you want is the count, you can use the fact that anything that implements `IList<T>` also implements `IEnumerable`; and furthermore there is an extension method in `System.Linq.Enumerable` that returns the count of any (generic) sequence:

```
var ienumerable = inputObject as IEnumerable;
if (ienumerable != null)
{
    var count = ienumerable.Cast<object>().Count();
}
```

The call to `Cast` is because out of the box [there isn't a `Count` on non-generic `IEnumerable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604168/count-for-ienumerable).

Comment: Ah, yes, I get it! But would I have to expect performance impacts with this implementation?

Comment: @remio yes, you would.  Because you're calling `Cast<object>`, you will not be able to benefit from the underlying list's `Count` property, so you will indeed iterate the entire list in order to count the items.  Furthermore, if the list's elements are of a value type, you'll have to box each of them because of the cast to `object`.