# How to Get Count of Items in Repeater inside ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have one `Repeater`

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptID" OnItemDataBound="repID_ItemDataBound">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <a href='example.com/somepage.aspx' id="myLink">
                 <%# Eval("MyVal")%> 
         </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In Code Behind I need to add one css class for this `<a>` tag when in repeater is one
Item

```
protected void repID_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
          e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      {
          //how to set this class only then count of items is equal with 1
          ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("myLink")).Attributes
                                                     .Add("class", "Count1");
      }
  }
```

Comment: You need to set it if the current item is the first item or if the datasource only contains one item?

Comment: How do you bind the data to your repeater?

Comment: @TroyCarlson only when datasource.count is 1

Comment: @Icarus  rptID.DataSource = myDataTable;
         rptID.DataBind();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you the count of your datasource items:

```
if (((IEnumerable)rptID.DataSource).Cast<object>().Count() == 1)
{
    ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("myLink")).Attributes
                                                 .Add("class", "Count1");
}
```

Counting the `IEnumerable` was borrowed from this thread: [Calculating Count for IEnumerable (Non Generic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604168/count-for-ienumerable)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but rpt.DataSource.Count doesn't exist, "Cannot resolve symbol Count" http://clip2net.com/s/i3t4Wl

Comment: maybe I need to use if(rpt.Items.Count==1) ?

Comment: I tried, but it gave me the same error "Cannot Resolve symbol 'ToList'", In suggestion I have only this options http://i.imgur.com/UPFVKdW.png

Comment: var rpt = Page.FindControl("rptID") as Repeater;// always gives me null :(

Comment: Yes it's available, but it is incremented in each itemDataBound, I must to check it at the last iteration to know realy count of Items

Comment: Your previous answer seems to solve the problem ((IEnumerable)rptID.DataSource).Cast<object>().Count() :)