# Why I should not always be using ICollection instead of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, icollection

I ended up in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604168/calculating-count-for-ienumerable-non-generic) post while searching for solutions to my problem - which led me to propose a new answer there - and - to be confronted with the following question:

Considering `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`, and all linq extensions apply to both interfaces, is there any scenario where I would benefit from working with an `IEnumerable` instead of an `ICollection` ?

The non generic `IEnumerable`, for instance, does not provide a `Count` extension.
Both `ICollection` interfaces do.

Given all `ICollection`, in any case, provide all functionality `IEnumerable` implement - since it itself implements it - why then would I opt for `IEnumerable` in place of `ICollection` ?

Backward compatibility with previous frameworks where `ICollection` was not available ?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is a parent interface of `ICollection`. So if your method only takes `ICollection<T>` it's not as re-usable as if it accepted `IEnumerable<T>`. Also note that many LINQ extension methods try to cast to `IList` or `ICollection` to use the property instead of enumerating the sequence. `Enumerable.Count` is optimized as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b,references).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: thanks Tim. The statement **So if you say that your method only take ICollection<T> it's not as re-usable as if you would take IEnumerable<T>** however does answer "why not use A instead of B, if A is B+". If by whatever circumstances IEnumerable is more widely used - it is still not a reason why not to be using ICollection, given ICollection is an IEnumerable (unless the above is wrong).

Comment: @Veverke unless there's a specific reason not to, you should always prefer the higher class in the hierarchy that has whatever you need. This gives more flexibility: if there's nothing specific in `ICollection` that you need, using `IEnumerable` gives more flexibility.

Comment: @Jcl: I agree and it's a strong point. However, as with my comment on one of Tim's statements above - I still think this *per se* does not answer the question. Luk's answer, below, on other hand, brings features that IEnumerable has over ICollection. IEnumerable may be way more frequent everywhere - but if I do not care about portability, then it does not even touch the question's point.

Comment: @Veverke `IEnumerable` doesn't have any feature over `ICollection`. Since it's a more simple contract, if anything, it has *less* features: `ICollection` has everything `IEnumerable` has (it implements `IEnumerable`), and then some more things. Also, I don't really see what portability has to do with all this. I think you are either mixing things here, or I'm not understanding you at all.

Comment: @Jcl: I am the one who is saying that ICollection has features over IEnumerable, not the contrary - hence the question. I meant, in the commentary above, that unless one does not show what IEnumerable has in addition to offer over ICollection, the question will remains unanswered. As for *portability* - I may have employed the wrong word - I meant compatibility. For reusability I do not see a difference in having the whole set of utilities one writes using ICollection. Unless, again, someone (like the proposed answer, by luk32, does) shows things ICollection lacks in comparison to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are actually two questions to answer here.

**When would I want `IEnumerable<T>`?**

Unlike other collection types and the language in general, queries on `IEnumerable`s are executed using lazy evaluation.  That means you can potentially perform several related queries in only enumeration.

It's worth noting that lazy evaluation doesn't interact nicely with side effects because multiple enumeration could then give different results, you need to keep this in mind when using it.  In a language like C#, lazy evaluation can be a very powerful tool but also a source of unexplained behaviour if you aren't careful.

**When would I not want `ICollection<T>`?**

`ICollection<T>` is a mutable interface, it exposes, amongst other things, add and remove methods.  Unless you want external things to be mutating your object's contents, you don't want to be returning it.  Likewise, you generally don't want to be passing it in as an argument for the same reason.

If you do want explicit mutability of the collection, by all means use `ICollection<T>`.

Additionally, unlike `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `ICollection<T>` is not covariant which reduces the flexibility of the type in certain use cases.

**Non-generic versions**

Things change a bit when it comes to the non-generic versions of these interfaces.  In this case, the only real difference between the two is the lazy evaluation offered by `IEnumerable` and the eager evaluation of `ICollection`.

I personally would tend to avoid the non-generic versions due to the lack of type safety and poor performance from boxing/unboxing in the case of value types.

**Summary**

If you want lazy evaluation, use `IEnumerable<T>`.  For eager evaluation and immutability use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.  For explicit mutability use `ICollection<T>.`

Comment: Thanks for adding the mutability aspect of ICollection - and the absence of it, in IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4):

`IEnumerable` provides a read-only interface to a collection and `ICollection` allows modification. Also `IEnumerable` needs just to know how to iterate over elements. `ICollection` has to provide more information.

This is semantically different. You don't always want to provide a functionality for modification of a collection.

There is a `IReadOnlyCollection` but it doesn't implement `ICollection`. This is a design of C#, that `ReadOnly` is a different stripped down interface.

The point made by Tim is quite important. The internal working for `Count` might be dramatically different. `IEnumerable` does not need to know how many elements it spans over. Collection has a Property, so it has to know how many elements it contains. That is another crucial difference.

Comment: Oh, here is a difference. Thanks !

Comment: Notice that this is true for the generic `ICollection<T>`, but not for the non-generic `ICollection`. For the non-generic version, the only difference against an `IEnumerable` is the syncing (having a sync root object) and the direct count.

Comment: Oh yeah I am a pacifist so I didn't touch non-generics at all, as I dislike boxing. I should probably expand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use the simplest contract (interface) which fulfills the requirements: `ICollection` is a collection, `IEnumerable` is a sequence. A sequence could have deferred execution, it could be infinite, etc. The interface `IEnumerable` just tells you that you can enumerate the sequence, that is all. This is different from `ICollection`, which represents an actual collection containing a finite number of items.

As you can see, these are quite different. You cannot ignore the semantics of these contracts, and just focus on which interface inherits which other one.

If your algorithm only involves enumeration of the input data, then it should take an `IEnumerable`. If you are, by contract, dealing with collections (i.e, you expect collections and nothing else), then you should use `ICollection`.

Comment: Could a sequence really be *infinite* ? I think infinity is an abstract concept with no real implementation that keeps its *infinite* nature intact. If we hold whatever sequence at hand at any given time, it is not finite anymore, because I am able to enumerate it.

Comment: @Veverke It is possible to have an infinite `IEnumerable` yes, all we need from an `IEnumerable` is an enumerator that describe how to move to the next element.  That description of how to `MoveNext()` could extend to infinity.  You cannot, of course, evaluate an infinite `IEnumerable` but you can evaluate a subset of it and that can, in some cases, be a useful approach.

Comment: @Veverke: the contract only requires the implementation to provide the next value when requested. Contrary to what you wrote, you do not "hold the sequence at hand". Here is an infinite sequence: `IEnumerable<int> InfiniteSequence() { while(true) yield return 0; }`. Try enumerating that sequence. If you want practical applications: providing live sensor-readings in a sequence.