# Casting string to IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, casting

I have `propertyValue` which is an object passed into my function.

I can assume that this is an `IEnumerable` of some kind, however due to the interface contract I must accept it as an `object` rather than directly as an `IEnumerable`.

When I try to cast my value to an `IEnumerable<object>`, so that I can get the length, I get an `InvalidCastException`.

```
var length = ((IEnumerable<object>) propertyValue).Cast<object>().Count();
```

I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by simply casting to `IEnumerable` rather than casting to `IEnumerable<object>`.

```
var length = ((IEnumerable) propertyValue).Cast<object>().Count();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Cast<object>()?

Comment: @VadimMartynov To use the `Count()` extension method, which is only available for generic `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @VadimMartynov On the non-generic class `IEnumerable`, there is no extension method for `Count()`. To use the method, I must cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` of some type.

Comment: You must not. Actually you should not because it causes boxing for char type.

Answer (score 7):

The `IEnumerable<T>` interface is covariant, but covariance doesn't work with value types. Casting a value type to reference type changes representation - the value needs to be boxed and the reference to the boxed value is returned. Casting reference types doesn't change representation - it's still the same reference, referencing the same object.

`string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, so it cannot be cast to `IEnumerable<object>`.

As mentioned in other answers, the solution is to cast to non-generic `IEnumerable`.

```
var length = ((IEnumerable) propertyValue).Cast<object>().Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

[String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the `IEnumerable<char>` interface, you can cast it to this interface

```
var length = ((IEnumerable<char>) propertyValue).Count();
```

For unknown types of collection you can cast it to IEnumerable and next enumerate values manually with your own [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604168/calculating-count-for-ienumerable-non-generic).

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static int Count(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        int res = 0;

        foreach (var item in source)
            res++;

        return res;
    }
}

var collection = propertyValue as IEnumerable;
if(collection != null)
{
    var length = collection.Count();
}
```

Using [Cast()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) method will cause to boxing of value types and it may have an performance issues for big collections.

Comment: Since the author does not know of which type the Enumerable is this won't necessary work always.

Comment: @dryman you are right, it's my fail. But Cast will result in boxing for value types. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should actually do what you need

```
var length = (propertyValue as IEnumerable<object>).Count();
```